# Central align subView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, subview

I'm trying to centre a `UIView` in another view (so like a pop up view), but whatever I do, I just cannot align it centrally!

```
func loadPopUpView() {
    let customView = CGRect(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, width: 100, height: 100)
    popUpView = UIView(frame: customView)
    popUpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(popUpView)

    popUpView.isHidden = false
}
```

I've changed the background colour to black just so I know when it appears.
I cannot do this with storyboard because it's going on a tableView, so I'm trying to do it programmatically. [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgfy3.png)

Comment: what customview is for?

Comment: On `CGRect(x:,y, width:, height:)`, the point (x,y) is the origin, not the center on. So either remove from x the width/t and y the height/2, or changed the center afterwards settings its frame `customView.center = view.center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to minus half value of your custom view height and width from x and y like below:

```
let customView = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 50, y: view.center.y - 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: Oh perfect thank you!
So is it always - 50 or is it because it should be half the `width` and `height` ?

Comment: @TsGDev Not always -50 it will be half value of your height or width as your UIView is square.

Comment: @TsGDev if my answer really help you then you can accept and upvote answer it will help other developer to find correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Absolute star, thank you! (I tried to upvote, but because I have < 15 rep I can't) :(

Comment: @TsGDev You can try now. It will take 15 min to accept answer.

Comment: Hi @TsGDev if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @TsGDev You can still upvote and accept answer if you have  < 15 rep.

Comment: Oh yeah I've upvoted it but it doesn't change the number, this is what it says when I press it "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @TsGDev You can'n even approve?

Comment: Ooh is that the little tick? Sorry new to stack overflow! I've pressed the tick beneath the down arrow :)

Comment: @TsGDev Yes, Thats why i have commented this. Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to put top left corner in the center, hence you need to let it get half size in position.

```
let customView = CGRect(x: view.center.x-50, y: view.center.y-50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Another solution is the use anchorpoints.

```
customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

On `CGRect(x:, y:, width:, height:)`, the point (x,y) is the origin. In iOS, that's the top left point.

On the [`CGRect` doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect):

> In the default Core Graphics coordinate space, the origin is located
>   in the lower-left corner of the rectangle and the rectangle extends
>   towards the upper-right corner. If the context has a
>   flipped-coordinate space—often the case on iOS—the origin is in the
>   upper-left corner and the rectangle extends towards the lower-right
>   corner.

So to fix this:

```
let width = 100.0
let height = 100.0
let customViewFrame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - width/2.0, y: view.center.y - height/2.0, width: width, height: height)
```

Another solution would be to apply the center once the frame (especially the width/size) have been set.

```
let customViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
customViewFrame = view.center
```